# ${parameter:?word} expansion for array range

Tags: bash, zsh, variable-substitution

[`${parameter:?word}`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#:%7E:text=assign%20word-,%24%7Bparameter%3A%3Fword%7D,-substitute%20parameter) prints the given error message if a variable is unset:

```
$ echo ${unset_var?badness}
bash: unset_var: badness
```

How to use this on an array?

```
$ array=(a b c)
$ echo "${array[@]:1:2}"
b c
```

With:

```
$ echo "${array[@]:1:2?Need at least two arguments}"
```

`bash` complains:

```
bash: array[@]: a: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "a")
```

`zsh` complains:

```
zsh: bad math expression: operator expected at `a least tw...'
```

---

This also "works" differently with positional parameters:

```
$ echo ${1?Argument not given}
bash: 1: Argument not given
```

We can print a range in an array, eg:

```
$ set a b c
$ echo ${@:2}
b c
```

Or, alternatively:

```
$ echo ${@:2:$#-1}
b c
```

`bash:`

```
$ set a b c
$ echo ${@:2?badness}
bash: @: 2?badness: `:' expected for conditional expression (error token is "badness")
$ echo ${@:2:$#-1?badness}
bash: @: 3-1?badness: `:' expected for conditional expression (error token is "badness")
```

`zsh`:

```
% set a b c
% echo ${@:2?badness}
zsh: bad math expression: ':' expected
% echo ${@:2:$#-1?badness}
zsh: bad math expression: ':' expected
```

Is there a way that works in both `{z,ba}sh`?

Comment: "2nd argument" is not a range. A range is "2nd to 4th argument". What do you expect to happen - report all the missing arguments, or report of all of them are missing? Also, for the second argument to exist, the first one must exist, too.

Comment: @ilkkachu I'd like to check that all elements are present.

Answer (score 1):

In zsh, you could do:

```
printf ' - "%s"\n' "${(@)a[1,4]}" "${a[5]?Need at least 5 elements}"
```

In bash as well, but only for non-sparse arrays as `${a[@]:0:5}` there like in ksh whose array design bash has mostly copied, that gives you the first 5 elements whose index is >= 0, so you may have more than 5 elements in there with the one with index 4 (bearing in mind that array indexes start at 0 instead of 1 in bash) unset, or the one of index 4 set but be the only one set.

```
a=( "${a[@]}" ) # unsparsify the array
printf ' - "%s"\n' "${a[@]:0:4}" "${a[4]?Need at least 5 elements}"
```

Or you could do the sensible thing and write it:

```
(( $#a >= 5 )) || die 'Need at least 5 elements.' # zsh
(( ${#a[@]} >= 5 )) || die 'Need at least 5 elements.' # ksh/bash (or zsh)
```

Instead of trying to be too fancy.